# Action on orbits defined by another action

Tags: equivalence-relations, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Let $(G,\Omega)$ be a transitive action of $G$ on $\Omega$. Let now $H\le G$ be a subgroup of $G$ and define $\Omega/H=\{\omega\cdot H|\omega\in\Omega\}$ as the set of the orbits generated by the action of $H$ on $\Omega$. I've already showed that
$$(\omega\cdot H)\cdot g=(\omega\cdot g)\cdot H,\text{ }\forall\omega\cdot H\in \Omega/H\text{ and }g\in G. $$is a group action of $G$ on $\Omega/H$.
I've problems in defining the stabilizer of a generic $\omega\cdot H\in\Omega/H$ in the action described.
Could you give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: We only have $Hg=gH$ for all $g$ if $H$ is normal, which is not assumed. Instead, $(\omega H)g=(\omega g)(g^{-1}Hg)$.

Comment: I think that an element $g\in G$ fixes an orbit $\omega\cdot H$ if maps the element $\omega$ in an elemet $\tilde\omega$ in the same orbit but I don't know how to algebrically describe this set...

Comment: The fact is that the action of G on $\Omega$ is not defined so it can be a generic action... I don't know if we can consider the coset because we don't know if it is a multiplication action

Comment: Such a stabilizer contains $H$. I don't know whether else, more characterizing, can be said about it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you (legitimately) use *right* actions?

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ acts on $\Omega $ transitively then, choosing some $\omega _0$ in $\Omega $, and letting $K$ be the stabilizer of $\omega _0$,  the map
$$
  g\in  G\mapsto  \omega _0g\in \Omega 
  $$
factors through the quotient
$
  K\backslash G = \{Kg: g\in G\},
  $
providing a equivariant bijection
$$
  K\backslash G \to  \Omega ,
  $$
so we may assume WLOG that $\Omega =K\backslash G$.

Now, the orbit space of the right action of the given subgroup $H$ on  $K\backslash G$ consists of the set of all "double
cosets"
$$
  \Omega /H = K\backslash G/H = \{KgH: g\in G\}.
  $$

Thus,  unless $H$ or $K$ are  normal,  as proposed by @Berci,  there is no sensible action of $G$ on that double coset space.  The
fundamental parameter "$g$" in $KgH$, protected on the left and right by $K$ and $H$, is too inaccessible to be acted upon in any meaningful way.

Comment: Why can I take a stabilizer of an element in $\Omega$ if the first request of the exercise Is "show that $\forall \omega\in \Omega Stab(\omega)$ Is trivial"

Comment: @Alchemist Why would the exercise's request prevent anyone from taking the stabilizer of an element? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Because I don't understand the meaning of considering the stabilizer of an element $\omega\in \Omega$ if we already know that it is trivial